# Facebook Graph API Updating Privacy Parameter

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

**Context**:

1. I have a facebook page with a post
2. I want to hide that post from anyone accessing the page (other than me) using the Facebook API
3. This can be achieved using the privacy field with "SELF"

**Problem**: Before I can even use it in my application, I cannot get a working example in the Graph API Explorer. I am using:

```
POST /v2.7/POST_ID?privacy={"value":"SELF"}
```

This works with other properties such as message, but despite many attempts, when I am able to actually set the privacy value property I always get the following message:

```
{
  "error": {
    "message": "(#100) Failed to edit object",
    "type": "OAuthException",
    "code": 100,
    "fbtrace_id": "DkL5f4bzK2E"
  }
}
```

**Question**: Can anyone provide a working example?

**References**:

- Graph Explorer: https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer
- Privacy Parameter: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/common-scenarios#privacy-param

Comment: Apps can only edit posts that were published via that same app in the first place.

Comment: Indeed that could have been the problem, but just tested creating a post through the app and then tried to modify its privacy and received the same error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After asking Facebook Support Team if it was a bug, it is not, their answer:

> You cannot edit the privacy of a post on a page . You can choose to
>   publish / unpublish it , if needed.
>
> To change the audience of the page itself, you will need to edit the
>   settings of the page.
>
> This is by design.

You can also see their answer directly: https://developers.facebook.com/bugs/152272141874454

Comment: Well in that case, attempting to publish or unpublish doesn't work either (see further down in that bug report).